# How to compute: $I_x =\int_0^1 t^x e^{-\frac{1}{1-t^2}} dt~~~x>0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, closed-form, gamma-function

$$I_x =\int_0^1 t^x e^{-\frac{1}{1-t^2}} dt~~~x>0$$

I first tried to see if I could solve the integer case.

$$I_n =\int_0^1 t^ne^{-\frac{1}{1-t^2}} dt $$

I have tried to find a possible relationship between $I_n $ and $I_{n+1}$ I could not get it after integration by parts the result does not look nice.

At some point I thought it is related to a Gamma function.But after the change of variables I did get a convincing out come.

Please help me to to evaluate $I_x$ or $I_n$

Comment: Thanks for correcting me. I am not english native:)

Comment: No problem; you could have fooled me (that English is not your native tongue.  You write well, and even native English speakers flip letters sometimes when they write!)

Comment: You might try looking at the Exponential Integral and see if that leads to anything useful.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Set $1/(1-t^2)=\tau$. Therefore
$$
I_x=(1/2)\int_1^\infty d\tau (\tau -1)^{-1/2} \tau ^{-3/2}\left(\frac{\tau-1}{\tau}\right)^{x/2}e^{-\tau}=(1/2)\int_1^\infty d\tau\ e^{-\tau} (\tau-1)^{\frac{x-1}{2}} \tau^{\frac{1}{2} (-x-3)}\ ,
$$
which Mathematica can solve in terms of a Meijer G-function (see above for equivalent Gradshteyn formula 3.384.4)
$$
I_x=\frac{1}{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right) G_{1,2}^{2,0}\left(1\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{x+3}{2} \\
 0,1 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)\ .
$$

Comment: Pleas what is Meijer G-function ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meijer_G-function